# magento - products in 2col_with_right_col and category lists in 3col layout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I a little confused at the moment.

I'd like to show the category lists in 3cols layout. That works.

But the products I'd like to show in 2cols with right col. I can change the layout for every single product - but I'd like to set this layout generally for all products.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use file catalog.xml in your template, for example:

magentofolder/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml (default/default should be your layout pages)

for anchod and non-nachor categories update:

`<catalog_category_default translate="label">` (non-anchor)

`<catalog_category_layered translate="label">` (anchor)

`<catalog_product_view translate="label">` Catalog Product View (Any)

edit row `<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>`

to

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
```

Comment: Mark my answer as a soluton by green tag on the left, to help others. thx